# javascript screen.width value difference chrome and safari when orientation change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, screen, orientation

When `window.orientation` is -90 or 90
Safari `screen.width` returns value of orientation 0's `screen.width`,
but Chrome `screen.width` returns value of orientation 0's `screen.height`.

I saw this

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
    var ori = window.orientation;
    var width = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;
});
```

But this only works in Safari. Is there other way get same value in Safari and Chrome?